# I have a trouble when I try to use JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery reference im my html , but I can't even run it. Why?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
alert(" Bemvindo Jquery ");


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>                     
<head>

<title > DOM  </title> 
<script  type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/root/Desktop/js/javascript/execute.js" >   </script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/root/Desktop/js/javascript/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" >   </script>


</head>

<body>

<center> <h2 > Bem vindo à pagina DOM </h2> </center>

<input type="text"  id="vlr" name="vlrentrada" > 
<button type="button" id="btnvalidar" >  VALIDAR  </button>     
<button type="button" id="teste" >  CLICK </button>    

</body>   
</html>
```

I have this message ; $ is not defined
    at execute.js:1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAyje.png)

Comment: The `<script>` tag for jQuery has to be before the one for your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

order change this

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/root/Desktop/js/javascript/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" >   </script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/root/Desktop/js/javascript/execute.js" >   </script>
```

first add main jquery then add execute.js cause if use $ tag then need to use main jquery library so in execute.js file you use $ tag but you add main jquery library later so first add main jquery library then execute.js

Comment: I can't even upvote cuz I've less 15 reputaion at the moment.

Comment: then please click green icon which mean best answer. it is place arrow button bellow . sorry for knock

Answer (score 0):

Load jquery before your script,

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/root/Desktop/js/javascript/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" ></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/root/Desktop/js/javascript/execute.js" ></script>
```